# how to get the output in pyspark same as got in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying some basic functions in pyspark like min max ect.
while using pandas df.min() I got all the separate columns and their minimum values like the image I have attached.
[image: Output of df.min()]

I need the same output using pyspark code.
but I don't know how to do that

Please help me on this

Comment: Please put data in tabular format

Comment: Yes i have add the image, hope its clear now

Comment: Can someone please assist me with this? Its very urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with below code,

```
# sample data
data = [(1,10,"a"), (2,10,"c"), (0, 100, "t")]
cols = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)
df.show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|  10|   a|
|   2|  10|   c|
|   0| 100|   t|
+----+----+----+

df.selectExpr([f"min({x}) as {x}"  for x in cols]).show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   0|  10|   a|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Iam using this data set "https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sagnik1511/car-insurance-data" 

getting error while using above comand
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [29], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df.selectExpr([f"min({x}) as {x}"  for x in cols]).show()

NameError: name 'cols' is not defined

​

Comment: please help me on this

Comment: You should declare cols variable and assign required columns in a list. if you need all the columns of dataframe you can define as - `cols = yourDF.columns`